# How to add a redirect to a web page where you have limited user priveledges

Tags: html

The company I work for has replaced our previously very flexible website with a much more restrictive "website in a box" technology.  I have my web pages hosted on Google Sites and would like to redirect people to those pages.  When I attempt to do this via javascript it gets stripped from the page when its saved.  I do not have access to the  section to attempt the depreciated  method of redirecting.

Is there another method available to automatically redirect a customer other than just posting a link in a restricted environment like this?

Comment: Do you use PHP at all?

Comment: Its not available to me in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're limited to using HTML to do the redirect, you can use a **meta redirect**:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

Though note that its use is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element) because it may be disorienting to the user.  In addition to the `<meta>` tag, you can add `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/">` to let search engines know that the targeted page is the canonical one.

---

**Edit:** if Google Sites won't allow you to change the `<head>` HTML, the Javascript, or the PHP, then it's time to go searching for solutions within Google Sites itself.  One solution that pops up pretty frequently in searches seems to be using a **URL Redirect Gadget**.

On the page you want to redirect from, click the *Edit Page* button, then *Insert Menu*, then *More Gadgets*.  Once there, search for "redirect gadgets" and some widgets that should help will show up.

These instructions are based on [advice given in the Google Products forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/Y-RTBG8PLV4).  I don't have a Google Site myself, so I can't verify that they work.

Comment: Thanks.  I might have not explained myself well enough above.  I had tried that and since I do not have access to any part of the HTML outside of the <body> tags I cant put <meta> tags in the <head> section of the HTML.  If I try putting them in the <body> they get stripped from the HTML when it is updated.

Comment: @techkilljoy hmm, no `<head>` HTML, eh?  I've updated my answer accordingly.  You may be able to use a URL Redirect gadget.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Im trying to redirect TO Sites from a proprietary website software package.  The package is one of those prefab websites you add a logo to and use a few page templates to create your site if that makes sense.  My previous experience with such software was that I could always embed javascript in a page or replace individual pages with my own HTML document.  Not the case here.  I kind of took it as a challenge to find a workaround.  Maybe there isnt one?